# iAD not working in iOS 5.1 devices but works on iOS 5.1 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iad

iAD not working in iOS 5.1 devices but works on iOS 5.1 simulator and iOS 5.0 devices and below version....
any know y is this happening....

already a question was posted by some one but still no ans....
[iAds (even iAd suite form apple's examples) stopped showing up on my iPhone, yet they run on the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643202/iads-even-iad-suite-form-apples-examples-stopped-showing-up-on-my-iphone-yet/9646185#9646185)

Thanks in advance if any one help me out of this

Comment: What do you mean with iAd? An iAd you created? An iAd in an App of yours? Please provide more informations!

Comment: if there were unanswered questions please provide a comment on it dont repeat the question again,it may lead to closure of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have linked to my question!

I checked today and it seems to be working fine! I have been researching for the past few days, there are lots of people having the same problem for the last few days(from all over the world). So I guess, it was a problem from Apple's side while giving out iAds.

Ideally, your iAds shud be working fine now. Atleast mine are and am hoping so are everyone elses.

Comment: thanks pat today iAD works like charm....any way thanks for ur help...keep up good work....